# How create such interface on Mac OS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface, osx-snow-leopard

Is there any framework?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It' either a custom, borderless `NSWindow` (see [MAAttachedWindow](http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass/) for a similar example), or an [`NSPopover`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (which is new in Lion).